# How to test if two electrons have the same or opposite spin?

Tags: electrons, quantum-entanglement

Suppose we have two electrons in close proximity. We have not yet measured the spin of each individual electron, and do not wish to measure the spin explicitly.

By what method can we now *test* if these two electrons in close proximity have the **same** spin, or **opposite** spin, without making an explicit measurement of the spin states of each electron?

Answer (score 2):

You have to measure their total spin projection on an axis. If it is:

$J_z = 0$, then the spins are opposite since:

$$|1, 0\rangle = \frac 1 {\sqrt 2}\big(|\uparrow\downarrow\rangle + |\downarrow\uparrow\rangle \big)$$

$$|0, 0\rangle = \frac 1 {\sqrt 2}\big(|\uparrow\downarrow\rangle - |\downarrow\uparrow\rangle \big)$$

while $|J=1,J_3=\pm 1\rangle$ have aligned spins.

Comment: Is "measuring their combined spin on an axis" done using the standard Stern Gerlach inhomogeneous magnetic field, or some other way?

Comment: @James So when I was at NASA, I wasn't allow to come within 1 meter of any (space) flight hardware, from lowly hex fastener  to Curiosity herself. So when I say measure, I mean "Apply the J_3 Operator". (It occurred to me, you don't need to know J, just J_3. +/-1 --> aligned, 0 --> antialigned).

Comment: Understood :) i just find this Harry Potter entanglement stuff strangely fascinating.